# Sharing image from webview to whatsapp

Tags: java, android, webview, android-studio, android-sharing

I have created an app which shows multiple webpages. I want that app to share image which is displayed on that webpage with whatsapp and other IM messengers, for that i have added a context menu and have implemented ACTION_SEND but it didn't work. When i try to share image it gives me error *"sharing failed please try again"* Here is my code

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {
private ProgressBar progress;
private WebView myWebView2;
private Menu optionsMenu;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);


    String url = "http://images.google.com";
    myWebView2 = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewTop);
    myWebView2.setWebChromeClient(new myWebViewClient());
    myWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
    progress.setMax(100);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    myWebView2.loadUrl(url);


    myWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
            View.loadUrl(url);
            TopRatedFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            return true;
        }
    });
    myWebView2.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
        Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    optionsMenu = menu;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.airport_menuRefresh:

            TopRatedFragment.this.myWebView2.reload();
            setRefreshActionButtonState(true);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "share image");
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getTitle()=="Call"){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "calling code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="share image")
        {

       // This is the code which i am using for share intent
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageState()));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image using"));
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This line looks strange

`share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageState()));`

The stream extra is supposed to contain the uri to the image you want to share, but you are setting it to something I don't even understand what it's supposed to do - that wouldn't even evaluate to a uri. 
Currently you are not supplying the intent with any information on WHAT content you want to send. Set the stream extra to the image location uri and you should be fine.

(Btw you really should compare strings using equals() rather than ==. And you shouldn't identify menu item on titles as it would fail when localized etc. Use the menu item id.)

Comment: Can you give me one example ? How do i add uri of image its one webpage.

Comment: Is the image opened in the webview or is a html document containing the image opened? I guess in that case you have to parse the HTML for the img element and get the src of the image.

Comment: It opens in webview not in a html document. How can i do that?

Comment: If the image is opened in the webview then simply get the url using webview.getUrl()

Comment: in the place of Environment.getExternalStorageState()));?

Comment: Yes. I have no idea why that code is even there. It's a method to get whether the SD card is mounted, how did you expect that to be passed as a url to your send intent...?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very informative. What goes wrong? Is there an exception?  Supply a log please.

Comment: Here is the log
W/System.err(13486):  java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://m.facebook.com/photo.php
W/System.err(13486):   at 
W/System.err(13486):  android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1066)
t
android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:921)
W/System.err(13486):   at 
W/System.err(13486):  android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:646)
W/System.err(13486):  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: When i try to share image on whatsapp there is no preview of it just blank screen.